# Symfony2 access repository query results of foreign key in php

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

How to access the foriegn keys in a query result when using find all repository method. In particular the Jobs_id foreign key, which is fetched into the jobs object.

```
$entities = $em->getRepository('btBundle:workHours')->findAll();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

using  foreach ($entities as $test) {
        $Id=$test->getId();  //Works fine
        $jobs=$test-getJobs(); // retrieves Jobs object.
        $jobs->getId(); // Error: Call to a member function getid() on a non-object   

}
```

As its saying its not an object i tried to treat it like an array by trying things like

```
$jobs[0];
$jobs['id'];
```

> which give the error Error: Cannot use object of type
>   Proxies.....\Entity\Jobs as array

Here is a dump of 1 instance of $jobs

```
Jobs {#709 ▼
  #clients: Clients {#710 ▶}
  #company: Company {#638 ▶}
  #scopes: PersistentCollection {#711 ▶}
  #workHours: PersistentCollection {#713 ▶}
  #userDetails: PersistentCollection {#715 ▶}
  -id: 101
  -description: "Test Job"
  -jobNumber: "7844.00"
  -task: null
  -currencies: "USD"
  -active: 1
}
```

Comment: is `$jobs` the same as `$Jobs` in php?

Comment: sorry that was a  typo, has been edited.

Comment: Can you provide you workHours and jobs entities definition?

Comment: Are you sure it's failing on all entities? Isn't possible that you have a WorkHours entity without related Jobs entity?

Comment: It's Mapped to Jobs, and and another entity called 'user' which is giving the same error. All the workhour properties are accessible though.

Comment: please add your jobs and workHours entity class also in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem is that you have some WorkHours without related Jobs.

And when you iterating over those entities `$test->getjobs()` returns `null` for those entities.

Comment: Your right, that was it. anyidea how to check if $jobs->getId(); exists? isset doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Check if $test->getJobs() returns Jobs object or null

Answer (score 0):

May be it is still a collection? Try to use get_class($jobs)?